# How to display key based values from a text file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a text file uplaoding process, where you can display the values based on a key such as **First Name**. Here is the sample text

`First Name : Joe
Last Name : Smith
Age : 21`

Now how can I display only the values which is based on the key?

```js
function process() {
                var input = fileInput.get(0);
                console.log(input);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                    var textFile = input.files[0];
                    reader.readAsText(textFile);
                    $(reader).on('load', processFile); 
            }

function processFile(e) {
            var file = e.target.result,
                results;
            if (file && file.length) {
                results = file.split("\n");
                var FirstName = results[0];
                var LastName = results[1];
                var Age = results[3];

                alert(FirstName);
                alert(LastName);
                alert(Age);
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="file" id="files" />
    <button id="upload" onclick="process()">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5gy7czey/) working in base of your code, the matter you got is the DOM selector of the input mine is this

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0];
```

nd the all demo is :

```
function process() {
                var input = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0];
                console.log(input);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                    var textFile = input.files[0];
                    reader.readAsText(textFile);
                    $(reader).on('load', processFile); 
            }

function processFile(e) {
    console.log(e);
            var file = e.target.result,
                results;
            if (file && file.length) {
                results = file.split("\n");
                var FirstName = results[0];
                var LastName = results[1];
                var Age = results[3];

                alert(FirstName);
                alert(LastName);
                alert(Age);
            }
        }
```